# Select text in a disabled textbox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox

How do I select the text in a disabled textbox?

Comment: If none of the answers below helps, consider letting us know if you mean WinForms, ASP.Net, or WPF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to be able to Select the Text, use `ReadOnly` attribute instead of disabling the control.

Answer (score 4):

Use `readonly` instead of disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `enabled=false` attribute, and add this to your codebehind:

```
 YourTextBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```